# WWW:Mechanize Perl Module install errors

Tags: perl, perl-module, nmake, www-mechanize

I am attempting to install the `WWW:Mechanize module` on my XAMMP server.  I have copied the test results that were displayed at the end of the install here:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\local\back.t         (Wstat: 256 Tests: 47 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  33
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t\local\click_button.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 19 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   15-17, 19
Files=51, Tests=554, 203 wallclock secs ( 0.51 usr +  0.11 sys =  0.62 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/51 test programs. 1/554 subtests failed.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' : return code '0xff'
Stop.
  PETDANCE/WWW-Mechanize-1.66.tar.gz
  nmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PETDANCE/WWW-Mechanize-1.66.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 PETDANCE/WWW-Mechanize-1.66.tar.gz           : make_test NO
```

Can anyone tell me why there are so many errors, and has `WWW:Mechanize` installed in spite of these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test 33 in `t/local/back.t` (in WWW::Mechanize 1.66 anyway) appears to test for 404s on a local loopback HTTP server, created just for testing.  It apparently received a different message than expected for the test.

I'd say you'd be fine installing it and ignoring that one test, since the other 553 seem to have succeeded.  You can do it by hand by downloading [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/) (or going to your CPAN build directory if you know where it is), and running

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test        # just try it again, it might have been transient
make install
```

You may also wish to visit the [WWW::Mechanize bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/www-mechanize/issues/list) and report this as a bug, if it persists; it would be nice.

---

**EDIT**: [More on this issue in the bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/www-mechanize/issues/detail?id=167), so apparently no need to report it.  No fix yet, though.

Comment: or, in cpan, just do `force install WWW::Mechanize`

Comment: ok - did the force install and the following 3 packages now show up in my perl-info page:  WWW::Mechanize::Image, WWW::Mechanize::Link, and WWW::Mechanize.  Does that mean it is working?  Is there a simple way to test if the package is actually installed correctly?

Comment: I ask because Perl keeps returning an error on this one line I have in a perl file; This is the line:  agent = WWW::Mechanize.new { |a| a.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'}   ->It cites an error "near" "{|"

Comment: `perl -MWWW::Mechanize -le'print $WWW::Mechanize::VERSION'` should output '1.66', which will at least show it's available in `@INC`.  After that, just start writing your script.

Comment: Yes, that's invalid Perl code.  Dunno what you're going for there, but `perl` can only understand Perl.  Has nothing to do with WWW::Mechanize.  Are you trying to write Ruby and expecting `perl` to understand it?

Comment: Nevermind, Mechanize installed correctly, thanks for the help!  Yeah I am a noob, copied bad code.  Thanks again!  The force install is what I used to overcome the error, I think?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I have analyzed this failure. At least to me it does not seem to be a WWW::Mechanize's bug.

Have a look at:

1/ my LWP (HTTP::Daemon) bug report - https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=62354

2/ my Socket (gethostbyaddr) bug report - http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=78364

--
kmx

P.S. sorry can post just 1 link